# Upload drive files via MS Graph API

Tags: c#, file-upload, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I’m trying to upload files (.xlsx less than 4MB) into a drive location via MS Graph API.

[Drive location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3JXa.png)

Please see the below code for more details I appriciate your help to resolve the issue currently facing based on the URL. Error - Resource not found for the segment Oks.

```
static public string DecodeData(string encodedData)
        {
            byte[] encodedDataAsBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
            string returnValue = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);
            return returnValue;
        }
        // Upload files to SharePoint
        public void SharePointUploadDriveItems(string accessToken)
        {
            var httpClient = new HttpClient();

            try
            {
                string path = @"C:\\StockLevelReportLocation\\New Files\\TestFileUpload.xlsx";
                byte[] filebytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path);

                using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    string fileName = "TestFileToUpload.txt";

                    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/root/Oks/Stock Report/TestFileUpload.xlsx/content"))
                    {
                        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata.metadata=verbose");
                        request.Content = new StringContent(DecodeData(Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes)), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII, "text/plain");
                        var driveItemsResponse = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
                        var driveItemsResponseContent = driveItemsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please specify the version of MS Graph you're using.

Comment: I'm using 6.31.0.0. My original issue was resolved but tucked with an error - {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header.","innerError":{"date":"2023-08-16T06:18:55","request-id":"f7b2b103-519b-4c44-83eb","client-request-id":"f7b2b103-519b-4c44-83eb"}}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing `:` at the beginning and at the end of the path in the URL. Another issue is that you didn't specify drive id

Your URL

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/root/Oks/Stock Report/TestFileUpload.xlsx/content
```

But it should be

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root:/Oks/Stock Report/TestFileUpload.xlsx:/content
```

Code

```
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive_id}/root:/Oks/Stock Report/TestFileUpload.xlsx:/content"))
{
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
    request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json;odata.metadata=verbose");
    request.Content = new StringContent(DecodeData(Convert.ToBase64String(filebytes)), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII, "text/plain");
    var driveItemsResponse = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
    var driveItemsResponseContent = driveItemsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Comment: Really appriciate your time to check this issue. After updating the URL still I'm getting the error - "code":"BadRequest","message":"Resource not found for the segment 'content'. Please let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: @KSampath I see that you didn't specify drive id drives/root vs. drives/{drive_id}/root

Comment: Thanks for your help in resolving the problem with the URL, but still I couldn't complete the API call based on the below error - {"error":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header.","innerError":{"date":"2023-08-15T07:19:02","request-id":"a8558023-9988-475c-8515","client-request-id":"a8558023-9988-475c-8515"}}}